# How to use Travis CI Environment Variable to set Meteor.settings?

Tags: meteor, travis-ci

How do I use Travis CI environment variables to set API keys in Meteor.settings? I've tried adding a new environment variable named `METEOR_SETTINGS` with:

```
'{
    "facebook_keys": {
        "app_id": "1234567890",
        "app_secret": "1234567890"
    },
    "instagram_keys": {
        "client_id": "1234567890",
        "client_secret": "1234567890",
        "access_token": "1234567890"
    }
}'
```

but I get the following error: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'app_id' of undefined**. All tests are running fine except the ones using `Meteor.settings`.

Comment: Looks like the `facebook_keys` didn't get populated into the Meteor.settings object. How are you adding the environment variable - with or without the single quotes?